# PHP submit not woking over post

Tags: php, sql

```
if (isset($_POST['button']) and $_POST['button'] == 'Join')
{
  include '../includes/db.inc.php';
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  $start = date("d-m-Y");
  $finish = 'NULL';
  $job = 'NULL';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO userproj SET user='$user', projectid='$id', datestart='$start', datestop='$finish', job='$job'";
  if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
  {
    $error = 'Error joining project';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
  }
}
```

that is supposed to fire off when this code:

```
<form name="form2" action="?goto=display&id=<?php htmlout($id); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($id); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Join"/>
</form>
```

is executed. Problem is it doesn't seem to. I have put an echo in there to see if it is firing but I got the rest of the code wrong but still nothing. It works when used as a get instead of post but then it redirects to the home page instead of the same page. I have two buttons that fail like this but every other post I have works. I can't see what I have done wrong but it all looks fine to me.

Thanks for taking the time to look.

Cheers,
Rob.

Comment: change the name of the button or change your condition to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`

Comment: please, show us the content of `htmlout()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure the browser is even supposed to send the value of type="submit". Why not just do if(isset($_POST['id'])) or add another hidden field?

Comment: Also this is not correct: `job='$job'`, because in job is `NULL`, then it will be `job='NULL'`, but it should be `job=NULL`.

Comment: @OlavKokovkin each browser is posting the value of submit button...

Comment: What?? He wants to join new project to the user, i.e. he needs to insert that to the database => insert query. Why update query???

Comment: I am inserting this into a many-to-many database that is seperate to the project and user databases. It needs to be insert because a new entry is being created. Also I actually want the data in the database to say 'NULL' which is why it isn't just NULL I don't want blank entries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct: `job='$job'`, because in job is `NULL`, then it will be `job='NULL'`, but it should be `job=NULL`. Also the same with `datestop`.

Change your query to this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userproj SET user='$user', projectid='$id', datestart='$start', datestop=$finish, job=$job";
```

Comment: lol... check sql manual.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html - you can do insert with using `SET`... using `(...) VALUES (...)` is old-fashioned way and also problematic...

Comment: holy crap... I havent used it before.. first time I seen this type of select query.. Thanks for the info btw.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?goto=display&id=<?php htmlout($id); ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using different name for button

```
<form name="form2" action="?goto=display&id=<?php htmlout($id); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($id); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="mesubmit" value="Join"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The button was orriginally called action, but that didn't work either. I'll try mesubmit and see if I get any joy.